# HTML5 Canvas mouse input with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How would I get the coordinates of a mouse click on an HTML5 canvas using Javascript?

Sorry I don't have a code example or anything, but this is a pretty simple question.

Comment: It's so simple there are [tons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element) of [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114465/getting-mouse-location-in-canvas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
    console.log('Clicked: ' + e.offsetX + ', ' + e.offsetY);
});
```

P.S. This solution assumes that you're using jQuery. This is definitely doable without jQuery.