# Detecting mouse location on iPad versus Desktop in Processing.js

Tags: ipad, canvas, processing, processing.js

I have this simple sketch in Processing in a file called `tmp.pde`:

```
void setup() {
  size( 640,480 );
}

void draw() {
  color bg = color(200);
  background(bg);
}


void mouseReleased() {
  println("(" + mouseX + ", " + mouseY + ")");
}
```

It runs perfectly in desktop (Java) mode. It also works perfectly in Javascript when viewed on a browser on the desktop.

Yet when I try and run it on the iPad, the first finger tap, wherever it happens on the canvas yields `mouseX` and `mouseY` of `(0, 0)`. Later taps return the correct coordinates but this first click is causing untold inconvenience as it upsets later calculations.

I have experimented with loading jQuery using a custom template to do so, then giving focus to the canvas, thus:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tmp').focus();
});
```

I have also looked at both these questions: [Detect mouse click location within canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10449890/1290420) and [Getting mouse location in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1114465/1290420) but they both deal with detecting the mouse location within JavaScript while I need to integrate the results in Processing.

I would appreciate any pointers.

### iPad Setup

1. I am running the app on my desktop browser on a given port, say `http://127.0.0.1:52956`
2. I use `ifconfig` to get my computer's IP address. In this case: `192.168.1.10`
3. With the iPad on the same wifi network, I point the browser to `http://192.168.1.10:52956`

Finally in case anyone is interested to see the consequences of this problem, my app is running here: http://bit.ly/facebuzzapp and you can see that it works well on desktop but not on iPad.

Comment: how are you running in the iPad?

Comment: Thanks @v.k. -- I have added a footnote on the iPad setup to my question. The actual code is [on github](https://github.com/gauden/facebuzz)