# The 'e' parameter in addEventListener

Tags: canvas, position, mouse, addeventlistener

I have a function which is called from an addEventListener (awesome Simon Sarris' one in [Getting mouse location in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114465/getting-mouse-location-in-canvas/10450761#10450761)).

The function requires a parameter 'e' to be called which used in 2 lines at the end of the function.

What is the parameter 'e' and how can that function be modified to prescend that parameter and get the mouse position being called from somewhere outside an event (like a setInterval)?

Sorry if this isn't the way to post a thread, I couldn't find a way to reply to that answer or send the author a message asking it.

Answer (score 1):

The "e" is the event object that the browser automatically sends to any function that wants to listen to mouse events.

It contains many properties including which object triggered the event and for mouse events it includes the mouse position.