# Keypress and mouse events

Tags: javascript, three.js, dom-events

I'm building a demo with Three.js (even though I want input to work the same way on any library)

I tried researching the subject of user input/events and there are just way to many answers that are using jQuery or some other library or attached to a web element.

I'm just learning so I would like to just stick with Vanilla JS.

I'm just looking for a way that if a keyboard button is pressed example if <kbd>W</kbd> pressed then `console.log("Key: 'W' was pressed");`.

Same for mouse input/event mouse position:

```
console.log(mouseX + ", " + mouseY);
```

the problem is finding bare bones samples that are vanilla JS. Just looking for a simple solution that I can later build up on for example:

1. return true if key or mouse button pressed
2. get position of mouse x and y
3. later add event queue for syncing with framerate/loop

I read that events/input can be challenging, just looking for a nudge in the right direction.

P.S. I wouldn't mind using a light weight library that simplifies this with maybe support for touch screens/mobile even controller input.

Mostly for gaming purposes.

Comment: Assuming a canvas, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/canvas-html5-real-mouse-position and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114465/getting-mouse-location-in-canvas for mouse x/y

Comment: var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

Comment: Are you using a `<canvas>` element (or any element at all, actually)?  Should work...

Comment: I believe that three.js will render to a canvas element as a fallback. Looking for events that happen with in the window/screen space of the document not only within a canvas or do I need to create a fake canvas full screen that gets covered by a GL context? (sorry little new for correct wording)

Comment: I think you can safely remove tag `three.js`.

Comment: Found the answer @ http://www.kirupa.com/html5/keyboard_events_in_javascript.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use my own modified version of THREEx.KeyboardState for keyboard input. It's not too complicated - it just subscribes to the **keyup** and **keydown** events on the document object and buffers all the events each frame. My game calls the `update` method each frame to cycle the buffer.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", this._onKeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", this._onKeyUp, false);
```

I wrote similar for the mouse and also for gamepads in Chrome. They are all fairly clean and straightforward. Hopefully that should give you some good examples to work from.

[The source can be viewed](https://github.com/BrianMacIntosh/bmacSdk/tree/master/input) on Github in Javascript or Typescript.